# К фотографиям добавляются прозрачные полосы

Tags: java, android

Добрый день.
Сразу оговорюсь, что я начинающий программист, сейчас делаю приложение, которое загружает фотографии на Parse.com.
Столкнулся с проблемой ориентации фотографий, загружаемых туда. 
Нашел на английском stackoverflow следующий код:

```
public static Bitmap scaleImage(Context context, Uri photoUri) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
    BitmapFactory.Options dbo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    dbo.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, dbo);
    is.close();

    int rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight;
    int orientation = getOrientation(context, photoUri);

    if (orientation == 90 || orientation == 270) {
        rotatedWidth = dbo.outHeight;
        rotatedHeight = dbo.outWidth;
    } else {
        rotatedWidth = dbo.outWidth;
        rotatedHeight = dbo.outHeight;
    }

    Bitmap srcBitmap;
    is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
    if (rotatedWidth > MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION || rotatedHeight > MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION) {
        float widthRatio = ((float) rotatedWidth) / ((float) MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION);
        float heightRatio = ((float) rotatedHeight) / ((float) MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION);
        float maxRatio = Math.max(widthRatio, heightRatio);

        // Create the bitmap from file
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = (int) maxRatio;
        srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
    } else {
        srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    }
    is.close();


    if (orientation > 0) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(orientation);

        srcBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBitmap, 0, 0, srcBitmap.getWidth(),
                srcBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }

    String type = context.getContentResolver().getType(photoUri);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    if (type.equals("image/png")) {
        srcBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 30, baos);
    } else if (type.equals("image/jpg") || type.equals("image/jpeg")) {
        srcBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, baos);
    }
    byte[] bMapArray = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);
}

public static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
            new String[]{MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION}, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.getCount() != 1) {
        return -1;
    }

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getInt(0);
}

public static Uri getImageContentUri(Context context, File imageFile) {
    String filePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID },
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=? ",
            new String[] { filePath }, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
        Uri baseUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media");
        return Uri.withAppendedPath(baseUri, "" + id);
    } else {
        if (imageFile.exists()) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
            return context.getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Я в нем пока что мало что понимаю, пытаюсь разобраться. 
Столкнулся со странной проблемой: при загрузке на Парс изображений к нему (изображению) добавляются две прозрачные (на прикрепленном фото они черные из-за последующего сохранения в Галерее из ImageView, на Парс отправляются с прозрачными) полосы. 
Это проблема в этой части кода или искать где-то еще, в другой части?

Очень надеюсь на помощь со стороны, пока что эта часть кода недосягаема.

**Первое фото - То, что я скачал с Парса впоследствии** (11кб)

**Второе фото - Оригинал** (1,3 мб)

[image: То, что я скачал с Парса впоследствии]
[image: Оригинал фото]

Answer (score 1):

Нашел причину.
Возможно, кому-то пригодится.

Сделав **iMageVIew** (из которого и берется фотография, отправляемая на Parse.com) атрибуты **android:width** и **android:height** = **wrap_content** (а не **match_parent**, как было до этого), проблема исчезает. 
Видимо, чтобы подогнать размеры **Image** к размеру экрана, и добавлялись эти полосы.

Если у кого-то есть другое объяснение или мысли по этому поводу, буду благодарен за разъяснения.